# Reading Laravel .env file with Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I want to store base url in .env file and read it with angular. Or maybe should i store that variable in angular config file ?

What are the best practices for it ?

Comment: Create a service or constant in angular and define your base url there. No need for a round trip to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read .env files from angular because this file is not public and client-side is obviously unreachable.

To expose some backend configuration you have some alternatives:

- expose a configuration api, call call it via $http when application is ready (use .run() ) and save the retrieved data in a service so you can share 
  configuration between frontend components
- create a backend service that renders into a js file and include this js file like a standard angular components
- use a server defined ng-init on your ng-app node in order to have access to the configuration through angular scopes

In my opinion, first one is the best.